# Codegen for CoreData entity not working in Xcode 11

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, codegen

So I am pretty new to CoreData in Xcode and I have been looking for tutorials to see how to get more familiar with it and start working with it. A tutorial I have been watching, mentions that we need to Generate code for an entity that I created. I select **Editor -> Create NSManagedObject** Subclass to generate the code for the entity. But the files generated come full of errors and warnings that I haven't caused. I will attach screenshots for some more details.

[image: Entity created in CoreData]

That's the entity that I am creating in CoreData

[image: First generated file]

That's the first generated file for the entity

[image: Second generated file]

That's the second file generated for the entity

The below are the errors and warnings I am getting:

```
File 'Person+CoreDataClass.swift' is part of module 'CoreData'; ignoring import

File 'Person+CoreDataProperties.swift' is part of module 'CoreData'; ignoring import

Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc

Cannot find type 'NSManagedObject' in scope

Cannot find type 'NSFetchRequest' in scope
```

Note that I have enabled CoreData when I first created the project and I haven't made any changes to any other files in the project.

I would appreciate any kind of help since I haven't got any experience yet with CoreData. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new project with a different name (not CoreData)

Comment: Well, that was it I guess I guess I still haven't learned to use restricted names for projects yet. Thank you anyways!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to help